# JS eval security issue

Tags: javascript

Everyone tells that eval() function in JS is BAD.

Actually I am using it this way:

```
eval("document.getElementById('toto').value");
```

In my opinion this is secure even if the user is sending malicious input in the "toto" element.

Can you confirm that please ? (I don't want to let vulnerabilities in my application).

Comment: How is this any different from just `document.getElementById('toto').value` without the eval?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Without the quotes it would, but with quotes...?

Comment: why is this secure? People can execute very JavaScript code they want, it's properbly the most unsecure way to use `eval`...

Comment: @Juhana - eval expects JS code in a string as argument.

Comment: @techfoobar Yes, and the JS code is `document.getElementById('toto').value`. You'd have to eval that *again* to execute the code contained in the input field.

Comment: In this particular case it doesn't pose security thread, but it really  bad code in all other senses.

Comment: @WouterJ: The person using the browser can do that anyway, on any modern browser, simply by opening the dev tools console and typing.

Comment: @Juhana - You're right. The above code actually does absolutely nothing!

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you need to execute code from an input?

Comment: @Juhana: I love how everyone else (including me) just read right past that, and even *corrected* you when you asked the question. Nice one, well observed!

Comment: Some of you guys got it wrong, i really meant:
eval("document.getElementById('toto').value");

with the double quotes. I need it to eval a string path. Now I'm not really discussing how to do it. I'm just telling i'm doing it this way and needed to know if it was breakable or not.
Of course without the quotes It would have been a vulnerability. But now with the quotes, I don't see any vulnerability. And that's what I wanted you to confirm ? :)

Comment: But why on earth would you want to wrap it in eval when you can just take the value directly? There's no point in it at all.

Answer (score 2):

First off, as Juhana points out in the comments, this:

```
eval("document.getElementById('toto').value");
```

is just an unnecessary use of `eval`, it equates to

```
document.getElementById('toto').value;
```

Now, **without** the quotes:

```
eval(document.getElementById('toto').value);
```

...it will evaluate whatever code is in the `input` with the `id` "toto".

Assuming that's what you meant:

It seems a bit odd to execute code someone's typed in an `input`, but as long as you're okay with three things, that's fine. The three things are:

1. `eval` will execute whatever code is in that input. Since the user put it there, odds are pretty good that's fine (it is, at least, a "user beware" situation).
2. `eval` fires up a full JavaScript parser. Now, on modern browsers that happens faster than an eye blink, so...
3. `eval` will execute the code you give it in the context where you're calling it, which gives it access even to the *local* variables in that context.

The "`eval` is evil" mantra relates to using `eval` unnecessarily, as people sometimes do (you see `eval("obj." + nameOfProperty)` for instance), and using it on content you don't control.

Comment: Not secure if there is the possibility that the user running this is not the user who fills up the value for `.toto`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Threrefore, you confirm that the first line of code (my line of code) is secure ? (even if it is unnecessary use of eval)

Comment: @cootscharles: LOL Yes, with the quotes, *completely* secure. :-)